# If $G,H$ are groups then $G\times H\cong H\times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This seems like a basic question, but I searched for a while and couldn't find it on the site.

I want to know if I have a valid proof for the following theorem. If it is correct, I'd like to see how a mathematician would write this proof (my proof doesn't seem very "tidy"). I'd like to see what shortcuts we can take to prove this, and how to choose better wording. I ask this simply because I wish to improve my proof-writing skills.

> If $G,H$ are groups then $G\times H\cong H\times G$.

My first step was proving that $G\times H$ and $H\times G$ are groups. To save time, I won't share my work for this step.

Step 2: Show $G\times H\cong H\times G$.

Let us denote the symbols for the operations of $G$ and $H$ as follows: $(G, *)$ and $(H,\odot)$. Also, let $A=(a_i,a_j)$ and $B=(b_i,b_j)$.

*(This next part is where my notation gets messy, unconventional and confusing. Please feel free to edit and change it to something more clear.)*

We must find a function $f$ such that: $$f\left(A \underset{G\times H}{\times} B\right)=f(A)\underset{H\times G}{\times}f(B)\;\;\forall A,B\in G\times H.$$

This can be written:
$$f \left( a_i*b_i,a_j\odot b_j  \right)    = f \left(  a_i,a_j \right)  \underset{H\times G}{\times} f \left(  b_i,b_j \right)  $$

We should choose the function $f(x,y)=(y,x)$. It is clearly a bijection from $G\times H$ to $H\times G$. Applying $f$, we have:

$$f \left( a_i*b_i,a_j\odot b_j  \right)=\left( a_j\odot b_j, a_i*b_i \right)$$

and

$$f \left(  a_i,a_j \right)  \underset{H\times G}{\times} f \left(  b_i,b_j \right)= \left(  a_j,a_i \right)\underset{H\times G}{\times} \left(  b_j,b_i \right)=\left( a_j\odot b_j, a_i*b_i \right).$$

Thus, we have a bijective function $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ which satisfies $f\left(A \underset{G\times H}{\times} B\right)=f(A)\underset{H\times G}{\times}f(B).$

$\therefore G\times H\cong H\times G$.

**Q.1**: Is this done properly?

**Q.2**: Can the proof be constructed in a more concise manner or worded better? What would a standard, conventional proof for this theorem look like?

Thank you.

Comment: @Timbuc he proved that this is the case perfectly well

Comment: What about using the ismorphism $(a,b)\mapsto(b,a)$

Comment: I misunderstood the question: no problem at all, @Alizter

Comment: Probably showing the product is a group has been done earlier in the book. The natural candidate for isomorphism works. The notation is not good, generic elements of $G$ should be called $a$ and $b$, and generic elements of $H$ $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the whole, your proof works perfectly well, and is written in a very readable, approachable way (though perhaps the formatting and symbol choice could use some help).

In practice, this proof would be made "concise" by leaving out the details that you've so helpfully left in, such as expressing the motivations for certain steps and your explicit definition of multiplication over $G \times H$.

As far a formatting goes: I think it would be clearer if you stuck to $*_G, *_H,*_{G \times H},*_{H \times G}$ for the product since the reuse of "$\times$" is confusing.  Also, elements of a group are traditionally named with lowercase letters, so $a,b$ rather than $A,B$.

Also, you should have $a = (a_1,a_2)$ rather than $(a_i,a_j)$; there is no reason for $i$ and $j$ here.

Comment: Is $i,j,k$ reserved only for Euclidean space? Also: should you write $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ or $f\left( (x,y) \right)=(y,x)$? Or perhaps $f\left[ (x,y) \right]=(y,x)$? I ask this because $f$ is not just a function of $x$ and $y$--it's the function of a coordinate

Comment: I prefer the last notation you used.  Unfortunately, you see the first, but strictly speaking either of the last two you gave are the correct way to go.  $i$ and $j$ are used when we want to allow arbitrary indices (usually $i$ and $j$ are arbitrary integers from $1$ to $n$).  In this proof, "$i$" always means $1$ and $j$ always means $2$, so there's no reason for the variable.

Comment: That makes sense--I have only really seen them used as indices anyway. Thanks for the help.